# Android - Sugar ORM database migration runs multiple times

Tags: android, sugarorm

I have an application that I built using Sugar ORM, and now with an app update I need to update the schema. I followed the documentation regarding database migration provided by [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/migration.html), and it seems to work most of the time. However, sometimes it appears that the upgrade runs more than once which causes a crash.

According to the docs I need to create a SQL script that is named according my schema version, and then put that into the `/assets/sugar-upgrades` folder. That has been done and here is my simple script.

```
ALTER TABLE SETTINGS ADD VBTTN_ADDRESS TEXT;
```

As you can see I'm simply adding a column to the `SETTINGS` table. After this step the docs say to set the new version schema in the `AndroidManifest.xml file`. This has also been done.

From there the update process is supposed to run the script agains the existing database, and it does that correctly. However, sometimes it appears to run the script a second time causing the following crash.

```
# Crashlytics - plaintext stacktrace downloaded by Paul Vinten at Fri, 22 Sep 2017 15:23:19 GMT
# URL: https://fabric.io/sl-labs/android/apps/com.myapp/issues/59bac986be077a4dcca10ad0?time=last-twenty-four-hours/sessions/59C512E5019C0001364FFFF2717BBDAC_a227484f9f9b11e7b44b56847afe9799_0_v2
# Organization: SL Labs
# Platform: android
# Application: Checkon.me
# Version: 1.4 (18)
# Bundle Identifier: com.myapp
# Issue #: 21
# Issue ID: 59bac986be077a4dcca10ad0
# Session ID: 59C512E5019C0001364FFFF2717BBDAC_a227484f9f9b11e7b44b56847afe9799_0_v2
# Date: 2017-09-22T13:40:44Z
# OS Version: 7.0
# Device: Galaxy S6
# RAM Free: 37.8%
# Disk Free: 85.4%

#0. Crashed: main: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

--

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.activities.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: VBTTN_ADDRESS (code 1): , while compiling: alter table SETTINGS add VBTTN_ADDRESS TEXT;
#################################################################
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
    (duplicate column name: VBTTN_ADDRESS (code 1): , while compiling: alter table SETTINGS add VBTTN_ADDRESS TEXT;)
#################################################################
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: VBTTN_ADDRESS (code 1): , while compiling: alter table SETTINGS add VBTTN_ADDRESS TEXT;
#################################################################
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
    (duplicate column name: VBTTN_ADDRESS (code 1): , while compiling: alter table SETTINGS add VBTTN_ADDRESS TEXT;)
#################################################################
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1005)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:570)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:2055)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1986)
       at com.orm.SchemaGenerator.executeScript(SchemaGenerator.java:97)
       at com.orm.SchemaGenerator.executeSugarUpgrade(SchemaGenerator.java:75)
       at com.orm.SchemaGenerator.doUpgrade(SchemaGenerator.java:52)
       at com.orm.SugarDb.onUpgrade(SugarDb.java:31)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:256)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
       at com.orm.SugarDb.getDB(SugarDb.java:36)
       at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:189)
       at com.orm.SugarRecord.listAll(SugarRecord.java:94)
       at com.myapp.model.Settings.getSettings(Settings.java:71)
       at com.myapp.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

#0. Crashed: main: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

#1. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2128)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:519)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#2. HeapTaskDaemon
       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(VMRuntime.java)
       at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run(Daemons.java:433)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#3. OkHttp ConnectionPool
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool.performCleanup(ConnectionPool.java:319)
       at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool.runCleanupUntilPoolIsEmpty(ConnectionPool.java:256)
       at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool.-wrap0(ConnectionPool.java)
       at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool$1.run(ConnectionPool.java:102)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#4. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2128)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:519)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#5. Crashlytics Report Uploader
       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:371)
       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:313)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.attemptUploadWithRetry(ReportUploader.java:188)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.onRun(ReportUploader.java:173)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#6. ReferenceQueueDaemon
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:150)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#7. Answers Events Handler1
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2128)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:201)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1084)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#8. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2128)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:519)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#9. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2128)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:519)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#10. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2128)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:519)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#11. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2128)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:519)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#12. Thread-11
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2128)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:201)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:438)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zzd(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoReflectionStrategy.getInfo(AdvertisingInfoReflectionStrategy.java:106)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoReflectionStrategy.getAdvertisingId(AdvertisingInfoReflectionStrategy.java:76)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoReflectionStrategy.getAdvertisingInfo(AdvertisingInfoReflectionStrategy.java:66)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoProvider.getAdvertisingInfoFromStrategies(AdvertisingInfoProvider.java:118)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoProvider.access$000(AdvertisingInfoProvider.java:28)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoProvider$1.onRun(AdvertisingInfoProvider.java:70)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#13. FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded(Daemons.java:269)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:249)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#14. FinalizerDaemon
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:407)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:188)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:209)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:204)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#15. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2128)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:519)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#16. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2128)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:519)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#17. Crashlytics Exception Handler1
       at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(VMStack.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1567)
       at java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1617)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.writeSessionEvent(CrashlyticsController.java:1114)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.writeFatal(CrashlyticsController.java:852)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.access$400(CrashlyticsController.java:59)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.call(CrashlyticsController.java:292)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.call(CrashlyticsController.java:285)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

#18. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2128)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:519)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Has anyone had this issue? Has anyone figured out how to resolve the issue?

** EDIT **
This issue occurs on release builds and not while in development. It also is intermittent. It is not something I've been able to replicate. Only my tester has replicated it and they cannot find a pattern other than installing the new version of the app over the old one. Some times the issue occurs but most of the time it does not.

Answer (score 0):

There should be problem with incremental builds. Give it a try with clean builds.

Make sure you disable instant run for Sugar ORM

Also Crashlytics increases build-id to sync with timestamp.
You can try to disable it for development env by adding this to your gradle file.

```
android {
   ...
   buildTypes {
      debug {
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
   }
}
```

Good luck

Emre

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but actually one thing I guess I didn't make clear is that this isn't an issue that occurs while debugging the app. It happens on a released version of the app.

Comment: hi, im having this issue as well, were you able to fix it?